# Chrome Native Push Notifications

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on Chrome push notifications using FCM, not thru Chrome apps or extensions, and was wondering how to push a json payload so that the browser would receive the same json payload and create a notification out of it. I've looked at the following and they all hardcode the notification:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/notifying-you-of-changes-to-notifications

I'm really familiar with mobile notifications but unsure how the browser receives a push. I've tried to push the same json format to as Android but it doesn't show up. Just want to take that json and build a notification with it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to check - [Error reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#error_reference) to see if there are any errors encountered. An error could occur when a gcm API function is called. Your app or extension should check `chrome.runtime.lastError` for more information in your callback. The error code will also be passed as a parameter to [`chrome.gcm.onSendError`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/gcm#event-onSendError) event.

Comment: You might also want to check this document about [Implementing Push Messaging for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en#implementing_push_messaging_for_chrome) which describes each step you need to complete in order to support push messaging in your web app.

Comment: That link has a more complete tutorial. Thanks @Mr.Rebot!